# Cannot launch kernel in Alea GPU (C#)

Tags: c#, gpu, aleagpu

I have been referencing the examples on Alea GPU's website (http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_3/doc/gpu_programming_csharp.html), but I am unable to get a Kernel to launch. I believe I have set everything up correctly but even their examples give compile issues.

Given a kernel of:

```
private static void Kernel(int[] result, int[] arg1, int[] arg2)
{
    var start = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    var stride = gridDim.x*blockDim.x;
    for (var i = start; i < result.Length; i += stride)
    {
        result[i] = arg1[i] + arg2[i];
    }
}
```

And the code to run it:

```
gpu.Launch(Kernel, lp, result, arg1, arg2);
```

Visual Studio (2017 Community) complains: 'Gpu' does not contain a definition for 'Launch' and no extension method 'Launch' accepting a first argument of type 'Gpu' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I believe I have Alea GPU set up properly. I used nuget to install both it and Fody as per the instructions on its site (http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_3/doc/installation.html). I also installed the F# package required for Alea GPU.

Is my installation correct? If so, am I using outdated documentation or is something else wrong with how I am trying to launch the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it while I was looking into alternative solutions. I needed to import Alea.CSharp in addition to Alea.

```
using Alea;
using Alea.CSharp;
```

Funnily enough, Visual Studio didn't prompt me to import Alea.CSharp until I had something else written that needed it, once I imported it I noticed that the error for gpu.Launch went away.

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is

```
var gpu = Gpu.Default;
gpu.Launch(...);
```

or

```
Gpu.Default.Launch(...);
```

and yes, you need

```
using Alea;
using Alea.CSharp;
```